# Troubleshoot UnknownResourceException when following AWS tutorial

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I'm attempting to follow [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/getting-started-example-helloworldworkflow.html) AWS tutorial. But I'm having trouble at "You can run GreeterWorker successfully at this point." as I'm getting an UnknownResourceException.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.model.UnknownResourceException: Unknown domain: helloWorldWalkthrough (Service: AmazonSimpleWorkflow; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnknownResourceFault; Request ID: xxxxx)
```

Steps taken

- Resolved permission exception by attaching the `SimpleWorkflowFullAccess` IAM Policy to my AWS user.
- Verified that the helloWorldWalkthrough is registered on the SWF dashboard
- registered new helloWorldWalkthrough2 domain, same error occured

The tutorial didn't cover the step about attaching the SimpleWorkflowFullAccess policy to the AWS user, so I'm wondering if there is a similar undocumented step to allow my user to find this domain.

My code is copy/pasted from the GreeterWorker class in the tutorial.

```
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.AmazonSimpleWorkflow;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.ActivityWorker;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.WorkflowWorker;

public class GreeterWorker  {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration().withSocketTimeout(70*1000);

     String swfAccessId = System.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID");
     String swfSecretKey = System.getenv("AWS_SECRET_KEY");
     AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(swfAccessId, swfSecretKey);

     AmazonSimpleWorkflow service = new AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient(awsCredentials, config);
     service.setEndpoint("https://swf.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");

     String domain = "helloWorldWalkthrough";
     String taskListToPoll = "HelloWorldList";

     ActivityWorker aw = new ActivityWorker(service, domain, taskListToPoll);
     aw.addActivitiesImplementation(new GreeterActivitiesImpl());
     aw.start();

     WorkflowWorker wfw = new WorkflowWorker(service, domain, taskListToPoll);
     wfw.addWorkflowImplementationType(GreeterWorkflowImpl.class);
     wfw.start();
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that both console and Java client use the same region?

Comment: The tutorial uses a hard-coded endpoint. If there was an instruction to edit that line for whatever region you were using I missed it. I was just using the defaults and never thought to check.

Comment: @gridDragon If you have found the solution, then can you please put it here so that others can get benefited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the domain using the console or through an api call. Domain is not created automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue and then I found that the region is hard coded in the main method inside `GreeterWorker` class as shown below:

```
service.setEndpoint("https://swf.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
```

However my SWF account was in west-2 region.

Answer (score 0):

I was also faving same problem. region is hard coded in tutorial.
I changed code as flllows

```
service.setEndpoint("https://swf.us-west-2.amazonaws.com");
```